# lotus notes does not display the image with img tag in body?

Tags: email, images, lotus-notes, email-client

i have my email body consisting below URL

```
   <img src="http://10.210.162.79:8000/web/getImage.do?actionCode=2&imageId=1008"/>
```

but image is not displayed(it displayed as cross icon). I also tried below setting

LotusNotes-Preferences-Mail-Internet-Image Security--Uncheck To ensure privacy do not show remote images without my permission

Same thing works on my collegue system but for me  it sill does not display image> Not sure what i am missing here?
I have already tried restarting of lotus notes. My lotus notes version is 8.5.

Comment: Is your colleague also using the same OS and version of Notes?  Do other Images show in emails as expected?  If you use a browser and navigate directly to that address does it show you the image?

Comment: What version of Notes? When you say that it works for your colleague, do you mean that the exact same email works for him but not for you, or just that a similar email works for him?

Comment: How about proxy- settings? Are they the same in both clients?